# probability that at least two part will be defective

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

### Question

> The probability that a part manufactured by a company will be defective is $0.05$. If $15$ such parts are selected randomly and inspected, then the probability that at least two part will be defective is ________. (round off to two decimal places)

### My Approach

$$P(\text{atleast 2 part defective})=1-P(\text{No part defective}) -P(\text{1 part defective})$$

$$=1-(0.95)^{15}-((0.95)^{14} \times 0.05)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Which is the "bad piece" among the $15$ possible ones that covers the $0..95^{14}\times 0.05$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite, $$P=1-(0.95)^{15}-{15\choose 1}((0.95)^{14} \times 0.05)$$